# 12 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record

Tags: c, char, malloc, doubly-linked-list

I'm using C and wanted to create a doubly linked list that contains char values. I have another file given to use by the teacher to measure the big O notation so I'm sure it's correct. But when I run it, I get a zsh: segmentation fault from the terminal.

I ran it through valgrind and it gave me the error mentioned in the title and mentioned the following function, more specifically the Malloc and strdup command. I'm not sure what's wrong here, it looks fine to me so was hoping to get some help here.

Here's the struct from the header file:

```
struct node
{
struct node *next;
struct node *prev;
char *value;
};
```

and here's the function to create a node in the main file:

```
static struct node *make_node(const char *value)
{
struct node *result = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
result->value = strdup(value);
result -> next = NULL;
result -> prev = NULL;
return result;
}
```

And for good measure, here's the function that calls make_node

```
ListPos list_insert(ListPos pos, const char *value)
{

struct node *node = make_node(value);

struct node *before = pos.node->prev;
struct node *after = pos.node;

node->next = after;
after->prev = node;

node->prev = before;
before->next = node;

pos.node = node;
return pos;
 }
```

Comment: How do you know that `pos.node->prev` (which you'll dereference) isn't `NULL`? Aren't there `NULL` pointers marking the ends of the list?

Comment: I have another function called list_end which checks for that @WeatherVane

Comment: if you mean that `before` and `after` *can* be `NULL` you should check them *here*. For example, if `before` is `NULL` then (perhaps) you need to modify the head pointer as there is no previous node.